# javascript, Javascript bug

Tags: javascript, browser, console

Run in console next code

```
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(1);
}, 2);
console.log(2);
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(3);
}, 1);
```

Why 4 values when has only 3?
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvwJH.png)

Comment: That code does not produce 4 values. [Here's proof that it doesn't.](https://jsfiddle.net/ypmoy23L/) Something else is printing out the `20`. For future reference, do not include console output or any other text as images. Copy the text and include it in your question. For one, it makes it more searchable.

Comment: You can tell something else is outputting 20 by the little arrow next to it.

Comment: You console log shows something called a "return value". The return value of a timeout is the ID for that timeout.

Comment: It is the `setTimeout` reference, try `var t = setTime..` then print `console.log(t)`. Now, why it shows only the first idk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a return value of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) in the console.

> The returned `timeoutID` is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to `setTimeout();` this value can be passed to [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to cancel the timeout.
>
> It may be helpful to be aware that `setTimeout()` and [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) share the same pool of IDs, and that `clearTimeout()` and [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) can technically be used interchangeably. For clarity, however, you should try to always match them to avoid confusion when maintaining your code

```js
console.log(setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('#' + 1);
}, 2));
console.log('#' + 2);
console.log(setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('#' + 3);
}, 1));
```